Authentication with Django Ninja, allauth or other solid solution?
I'm creating an API with django ninja, and I wanted to implement user authentication and accounts. I like allauth for it's social account functionality built in, as I plan for users to be able to link steam/xbox accounts and I've seen you can use this with drf relatively easily? Can I implement it with django ninja, or is there any other good authentication for ninja specifically.
Also, will I need token authentication for this if at some point in the future it may interface with a mobile application? Thanks for the support.
